# achart engine barchart cannot show the value < 0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, achartengine

I'm using AChartEngine but the bar chart cannot show the value of y Axis that <0
Both two charts below using same data but the bar chart cannot show the value that less than zero?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an older version of AChartEngine. You can either upgrade to 1.1.0 or download the nighly build 1.2.0 version [here](https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.2.0/).

Comment: Currently I'm using 1.1.0